# Choose boxplots (columns) to show in the matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

I read the [boxplot documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html).

But i don't understand how display some columns in my matrix (not all just a few).

I tried this:

```
%data is a matrix with 5 columns
%I want to display the second and third column only
boxplot(data,{2,3})
```

I know that is a simple problem but i find nothing in google or matlab documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only a few columns, just use indexing into the matrix. For example, to display only columns `2` and `3`:

```
boxplot(data(:,[2 3]))
```